# VS code stucks at free() in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linked-list

I have a rather strange problem, which could be trivial but I can't find the cause:
I wrote some standard functions on linked lists and in particular when I execute the element deletion function, VScode freezes as soon as it gets to free().
I quickly checked the code on multiple online compilers and it works so it must be a VScode problem.

Function:

```
void deleteData(Node** head, int data){
if(*head == NULL) return;

if((*head)->data == data){
    Node *tempPtr = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(tempPtr);
}

Node *prevPtr = NULL;
Node *currPtr = *head;

while(currPtr != NULL){
    if(currPtr->data == data){
        Node *tempPtr = currPtr;
        prevPtr->next = currPtr->next;
        currPtr = currPtr->next;
        free(tempPtr);
    }
    else{
        prevPtr = currPtr;
        currPtr = currPtr->next;
    }
}

}
```

Screenshot of the "error":

[image]

It's strange because it behaves as if I had put a breakpoint at that point but that's not the case so I don't understand what it could depend on.

Comment: You have a special case for the data being the head node. But then your code continue to go through with the next part, even though it's not needed. Or can the list contain multiple instances of `data`?

Comment: As for your problem, do you mean that the whole editor "freeze" and becomes unresponsive? Or that your program crashes?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The editor freezes

Comment: I think it is also important to point out that there is always the option to directly compile the unit and run it from a terminal, rather than depending on Visual Studio Code in order to achieve that effect -- or any other editor/IDE for that matter.

Comment: @Andrei-PaulIonescu Obviously, but I would still like to understand what this problem depends on

Comment: @Andrei-PaulIonescu running it from the terminal would mean that the debugger cannot be used. Personally I like the VSC debugger way more than a gdb on command line.

Comment: Not related to freezing, but if you have a hit on the first and second node in the list, you will dereference a `NULL` pointer in `prevPtr->next = currPtr->next;`. Is it possible to have multiple nodes with same entry?

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Gerhardh, `if((*head)->data == data)` should be a *loop*.

Comment: A less confusing approach, perhaps, is to abstract the double-pointer in a separate structure, `struct list { struct node *head; };`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue most likely arrises due to the fact that your code introduces a segmentation fault, a feat which is not generally identified at compile time, hence why some online compilers might have not complained, for it is a run-time error, nonetheless, software exists to determine such errors through various processes which far surpass the scope of this question (more modern compilers include this functionality, that's why I specified that such errors are not generally found at compilation, especially when dealing with older and legacy technologies such as C); so for now it's important to know that most modern IDEs use these tools and that they mimic the effects, or rather they anticipate the side-effects of running the code.

Now back to the actual error, within the while loop which spans from lines 59-72, you seem to omit to check whether prevPtr is NULL, which if it is you but dereference NULL which is not an allowed operation.

```c
while(currPtr != NULL){
    if(currPtr->data == data){
        Node *tempPtr = currPtr;
        
        if(prevPtr != NULL){
            prevPtr->next = currPtr->next;
        }
        else{
            *head = currPtr->next;
        }
        
        currPtr = currPtr->next;
        free(tempPtr);
    }
    else{
        prevPtr = currPtr;
        currPtr = currPtr->next;
    }
}

if (currPtr == NULL && prevPtr != NULL) {
    prevPtr->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it freezes anyway at free()

Comment: Also, there might be an issue when the target is the last node/cell of the list. Let me know if that is a problem, or whether or not this code helped you so that, in case it did not work as intended I can update the answer based on what else you encounter.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, I modified the code to ensure that a problem does not arise if the last node is to be removed, let me know if the freezing still persists, if it does I would suggest to at least try to run it with a compiler directly in the terminal and see if it solves the deletion problem, for if it does and the compiler does not complain this might mean that the issue is with VS Code and not the code.

Comment: Yes the freezing persists